# I forked up my commit history?

Tags: git, github

I'm relatively new to git so I'm sure I didn't handle this correctly.

Instead of forking off a repository from Github I just pulled from it and then reset my remote origin to a private repo on my own account. I used new branches to create features or fix some bugs sometimes but not consistently.

This was about a month ago and the changes I made are not wanted in the original repo but there are some changes I want to pull from the master branch.

Having my background details, **how would I go about pulling those changes without screwing up my commit history?** I've read some about merging and rebasing but I really only have practice merging from branches on the same repo locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the original repo as a remote (see [documentation on github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/))

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then you can do things like rebase off upstream/master (if you want to match the history of the upstream branch) or merge (if you don't care about diverging from the upstream project commit history). Something like

```
git fetch --all
git merge upstream/master # or git rebase upstream/master
```